# DWORD to REAL conversion

Tags: plc

I have been writing a program which reads values of reactive power from power analysed over Modbus RTU.

Reactive power is represented by 32 bits while the MSb determine the sign. Program doesn't read the whole 32 bits instead of it reads two 16 bits words.

After reading 32 bits I need to convert the value into REAL 
data type. So I wrote following conversion code in Structured text:

```
rQs: REAL := 0.0;
rQs := DINT_TO_REAL(DWORD_TO_DINT((SHL(WORD_TO_DWORD(stLovato_power.iQ_HW),16) + WORD_TO_DWORD(stLovato_power.iQ_LW))))/100.0;
```

(structure stLovato_power contains in its items 16 bits words, which forms 32 bits representation of reactive power).

It seems that reading is OK but something in the conversion is wrong. I still get 0 despite the values in iQ_HW and iQ_LW are nonzero. Can somebody tell me

Where I have done a mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code line and the conversion worked well using TwinCat3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem. The code was correct, but the program module wasn´t processed by the processor. Most of the module variables had got some values (these values were actually computed in different modules) and due to I meant that the module was processed. Excuse me.